# NSPlaceholders and Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift2, cocoa-bindings

I'm looking at the `.selection` of an Array Controller and I want to know when the selection is multiple values or none.  In ObjC we'd do this by getting the selection as an `id` and checking it's raw equality with the various placeholder markers: `NSMultipleValuesMarker`, `NSNoSelectionMarker`, and `NSNotApplicableMarker`.

But this doesn't work in Swift:

```
    let currentValue = eventsArrayController.selection.valueForKey("enabled")

    if let markerVal = currentValue  {
        if markerVal == NSMultipleValuesMarker {
            // this doesn't compile, AnyObject's can't be compared with ==
        }
        switch markerVal {
            case NSNoValueMarker:
            // this doesn't compile, an AnyObject is not a valid pattern
        }
    }
```

How do I test the value of placeholder markers in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, `==` is meant to check for value equality (that is, if two objects contain the same data, regardless of whether they share the same memory location or not). Use the `===` operator to check for reference equality (which tests if two objects share the same memory location).